# Dynamic compression in IIS 7.5 only for content bigger than NNN bytes

Tags: iis, dynamic, compression, size, administration

I turn on dynamic content compression in IIS 7.5 server - server responses are compressed now.

But there is bad compression ratio for small responses - I would like to exclude these small responses from compression.

I tried to set *httpCompression* attribute *minFileSizeForComp* to 32000 bytes, but it is not working - 150 bytes long dynamic responses are compressed into 250 bytes long responses (Fiddler).

How can I specify minimal contetn size, which should be dynamically compressed?

**EDIT1 - part of IIS config:**

*C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe list config -section:httpCompression*

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" minFileSizeForComp="32000">
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" staticCompressionLevel="9" dynamicCompressionLevel="4" />
  </httpCompression>
</system.webServer>
```

**EDIT2:**

I tried **static** http compression with small files (< 32 000 bytes) and they are compressed too.
Why *minFileSizeForComp* is not working for me?

Comment: From the name, min *File* SizeForComp, it would seem like that setting only applies to files (i.e. static content). I would expect that it would require a `Content-Length` header in dynamic content to even consider working, though.

Comment: @Gabe: I know what you mean...
In config(see added edit1), attribute minFileSizeForComp seems to be common for staticTypes and dynamicTypes. In IIS GUI manager, "Only compress files larger than" is part of static compression settings.
Content-Length header in dynamic content response is properly set - but it is length of compressed content.

Comment: `minFileSizeForComp` is in *kilobytes*, so `32000` really means 32,000,000 bytes. I wonder if it thinks your value is too big and ignores it.

Comment: @Gabe: According to documentation, that value is in kilobytes - but in IIS manager, that same value is loaded into editbox described as [Only compress files larger than (in bytes)]. Default value for IIS 7.5 is 2700 (?? 2.7 MB web response), so I suppose MSDN documentation is wrong. But I temporary changed minFileSizeForComp to 1 - no effect, small files are still compressed.

Comment: Honestly, you're probably going to be better-off asking your question at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: +1 Too bad we IIS doesn't seem to support this - even though you asked on Christmas!

Comment: Its because dynamic compression kicks in after the static compression. So basically what happens is Static compression is skipped (because of the file size constraint), but if you have dynamic compression enabled on the same mime type, it will compress the file if its smaller than the size or not. Dynamic compression seems to ignore this setting (minFileSizeForComp) - see [this link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2016/05/23/iis-respects-minfilesizeforcomp-for-static-compression/)